# MonoTouch 5.0: Get MonoDevelop to use iOS 5 SDK/Simulator

Tags: xamarin.ios, ios-simulator, monodevelop, ios5

I upgraded to Lion, MonoDevelop 2.8 and MonoTouch 5.0 and the Apple iOS 5 SDK. All smooth.

I installed the iOS 5 SDK into a different-than-default folder.

How do I get MonoTouch to use the new simulator? Under the menu *Project/iPhone Simulator Target* only 4.3 and below appear. However, I can set the OS target of the project in properties to 5.0

Perhaps MonoTouch needs to be told where 5.0 is?

How?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tell MonoDevelop where to look ?

1. Use **MonoDevelop** menu;
2. Select **Preferences...*** item;
3. Under **Others** select **SDK Locations** in the left tree view;
4. Select *manuall* the location of the iOS5 SDK

i.e. the one at the *default* location is likely the iOS 4.3 SDK

**UPDATE!** *5. Restart MonoDevelop*

Comment: I had to restart MonoDevelop, but 5.0 now correctly appears in the lists. I set the target simulator to default.